# How to refresh a part of a web page using Javascript or using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I refresh a particular part of a web page with a time interval (not entire page)?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do... the question is too vague IMO.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have a DIV in your your Web Page that you want to refresh :

```
<div id="myDiv"> </div>
```

To refresh it using javascript you just have to select it and change the html code :

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHtml = "Your new html code to display"
```

If you want to deal with forms, database queries ...
You have to use AJAX to call some php scripts for example without reloading the current page ...

Answer (score 2):

**You can use Ajax for your purpose.
suppose you want to check username availability before registering a user to your site.**

**create a request object asynchronously**

> function createRequest()
>
> {
>
> `try{`
>
> ```
>  request=new XMLHttpRequest();
> ```
>
> `} catch(tryMS){`
>
> ```
>     try{
>
>         request=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
>
>     } catch(otherMS){
>
>          try{
>
>              request=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
>
>          } catch(failed) {
>
>              request=null;
>          }
>
>     }
>
> }
>
> return request;
> ```
>
> }

**Next is the code to send a asynchronous request**

> function checkAvailability (username) {
>
> ```
>  request=createRequest();
>
>  if(request==null){
>
>    alert("Ajax request not possible on your browser");
>
>    return;
>
>  }
>
>  var url="checkAvailability?username="+username;
>
>  request.open("GET", url, true);
>
>  request.onreadystatechange = showStatus;
>
>  request.send(null);
> ```
>
> }

**Track the response**

> function showStatus () {
>
> ```
> if(request.readyState == 4) {
>
> if(request.status == 200) {
>
>   var response = request.responseText;
>
>           if(response == 1){
>
>               //username available
>
>           } else{
>
>               //username not available
>
>           } 
>
>   }
>    
> }
> ```
>
> }

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about AJAX

Look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ for jQuery

But please consider learning the underlying javascript language - you will be better for it in the long run 
here is a simple example
http://www.degraeve.com/reference/simple-ajax-example.php

The history behind ajax can be found here http://www.adaptivepath.com/ideas/ajax-new-approach-web-applications